# Is there a away to stream pre-recorded videos to Twitch/YouTube without re-encoding them?

Tags: video, streaming, youtube, obs-studio, twitch

I have a low powered server with a few videos that I would like to live stream to Youtube or Twitch. the problem is most streaming software (like OBS) require to re-encode the video before streaming it ( guess to add overlays and other audio streams maybe?) and my poor server just can't handle it. the videos are already encoded using h.264 and have a fairly low bitrate. my internet is more than capable of streaming at such bitrates but I can't find a software to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok apparently you can do it with FFmpeg like this

```
ffmpeg -re -i my_video.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://live-fra.twitch.tv/app/{key_here}
```

Note: The `live-fra` in the URL above stands for the Twitch server in Frankfurt. Please check [Twitch ingest endpoints](https://stream.twitch.tv/ingests/) to let Twitch suggest which server might be optimal for you to stream to. Personally, for me, changing the URL from `live-fra` to `live-syd` (Sydney) made a huge difference!